# Java Spring Webflux, logging the time taken for an outbound http call

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Small question regarding how to log the time spent for a http request please.

To avoid confusion, this question is regarding logs (not metrics), this question is about Webflux, this question is about outbound call, I am the client, trying to make a call to a server, and I need to time this operation, but from a log perspective.

Based on this snippet I am using:

```
 @Override
    public Mono<String> sendOutboundRequest() {
        return webClient.post().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
```

So far, I tried `.log()` but this is not writing the time spent directly, this solution needs another layer of parsing of the timestamp from the on subscribe and the on complete of log4j time.

I also tried `.metrics()`, this gets the time, but this only generates metrics, not a log.

I also tried some method execution surround

```
 long start = System.nanoTime();
        Mono<String> result = webClientIdms.post().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
        long end = System.nanoTime() - start;
        LOGGER.info("this will not print the actual http request time " + end);
        return result;
```

but this is not working, since in a reactive stack, this will not time the execution of the request when the reactive pipeline is executed.

May I ask what is the proper way to log the time taken please?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking to do this in a reusable way, you can utilise an `ExchangeFilterFunction`. You can find further examples of an `ExchangeFilterFunction` on the [spring reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-filter)

Below is an example implementation of an `ExchangeFilterFunction` that will time each external api call made by a `WebClient` and log the results. This takes inspiration from [MetricsWebClientFilterFunction](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/reactive/client/MetricsWebClientFilterFunction.java)

```
@Component
public class MetricsLoggingExchangeFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MetricsLoggingExchangeFilterFunction.class);
    private static final String METRICS_WEBCLIENT_START_TIME = MetricsLoggingExchangeFilterFunction.class.getName() + ".START_TIME";

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
        return next.exchange(request).doOnEach((signal) -> {
            if (!signal.isOnComplete()) {
                Long startTime = signal.getContextView().get(METRICS_WEBCLIENT_START_TIME);
                long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                LOGGER.info("Downstream called taken {}ms", duration);
            }
        }).contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(METRICS_WEBCLIENT_START_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

You can then add this to any `WebClient` instances that you want to log the duration using the provided `WebClient.Builder` ie.

```
WebClient.builder().filter(metricsLoggingExchangeFilterFunction).build()
```

Comment: Nice one, but I'm doubting if setting the start time on the context is correct. Wont it then also include the time it takes for all the upstream subscribes?

Comment: no, it just times the web client call. You can test this by artificially adding a delay on your reactive stream before or after the web client call. You should see that the time calculated from the `ExchangeFilterFunction` above doesn't include that artificial delay. Happy to remove the answer if this is proven wrong.

Comment: The delay itself also happens on execution, so it makes sense that that is not taken in, however, the subscribe of the delay is. That is probably not going to even take time in the range of millis, but if there is something upstream that does take more time on subscribe it might affect the measurement.

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context.write
"In order to populate the Context, which can only be done at subscription time, you need to use the contextWrite operator." and "starting with the final subscribe and moving up the chain."

Comment: Is there any easy way to simulate a slow subscriber? The best way to verify this is via a test. Also, if this is not working as expected we should prove it and then raise an issue against spring-boot as they are using the same mechanism to time api calls made via the WebClient.

Comment: Put a bunch of flatmaps between the doOnEach() and .contextWrite. If I add 50x ".flatMap(it -> Mono.just(it + "hi"))" it adds 150 ms (~10 -> ~160)
I tried it with .doOnSubscribe(() -> thead.sleep(1000)) but that did not influence it. I did expect it

Comment: I applied the same test to 2 locations. Inside the exchange filter function and as part of the reactive stream outside of the exchange filter function. I applied ~150 flatMaps in both cases. Inside the filter function saw the latency change by ~2ms. Outside of the filter function but part of the same reactive stream saw zero change in latency. I don't see any evidence that the latency calculated is impacted by code outside of the ExchangeFilterFunction class.

Comment: I guess that means subscription happens on the fly with this filter setup? So its not actually subscribing everything first and then running the whole pipeline. In that case I did test it totally different than what you did. So I guess it really does matter where you use it if it will work or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure to set the start time during the execution phase of the reactive pipeline. You can do that with something like Mono.defer or Mono.fromRunnable

```
AtomicLong start = new AtomicLong();
Mono.fromRunnable(() -> start.set(System.nanoTime())
    .then(webClient.post()...)
    .doOnNext(it -> LOGGEER.info("time spent {}",System.nanoTime() - start.get());
```

Comment: Giving this a try, many thanks for the answer