# Time elapsed time in Mono calls, mapping both success and error cases

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactor

I'm using a WebClient to call a downstream service, and I would like to log the elapsed time of the calls, both in the case of success and in the case of error.

The `elapsed` and `timed` operators work fine for the success case, but when you have an error, e.g., a 500 returned from the downstream service, or a timeout, the subscriber receives just a throwable, not a throwable + elapsed time.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446374/java-spring-webflux-logging-the-time-taken-for-an-outbound-http-call/66463480#66463480

Comment: possibly yes @MichaelMcFadyen this is similar to that question -- though what I would like to understand is how to do this in reactor.  I think this should be possible right?  No one else thinks this is useful?  All the solutions I've seen involve creating a variable outside the reactive stream, or working on the underlying http client implementation

Comment: No idea why this has a DV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "simple" way I'm aware of to do this in a general case for errors in a reactive stream. Once an error occurs that's it - you break outside of the normal reactive flow, timings included, so that information is lost.

However, an alternative in the case of webclient specifically would be to make sure you don't throw the error at all, using the `exchange()` rather than `retrieve()` semantics, similar to:

```
client.get()
        .uri("https://httpstat.us/500")
        .exchangeToMono(cr -> cr.bodyToMono(String.class))
        .timed()
        .doOnNext(s -> {
            System.out.println("ELAPSED: " + s.elapsedSinceSubscription().toMillis());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: the `metrics` operator does what I need; I needed the numbers to populate metrics, and it's far better to let Reactor take care of that.

[However, a general way to get the elapsed time for error signals, without resorting to objects created outside of Reactor still seems a useful thing to have.]